# Unit Test Guidance for Selenium Web Scraping

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, unit-tests, pytest

I'm working through https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/ and trying to connect the concepts to a program I'm writing.

Specifically, I want to write some unit tests, but I'm having trouble thinking of tests that don't replicate the assert statements already included in my code.

I know I could write things like a unit test to confirm that the program fails if it goes to the wrong URL, but that seems like overkill. Or is it?

I don't want anyone to write the tests for me, but can you point to parts of my code that you would expect a professional QA developer to test?

Thanks!

```
import logging
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import sys
import time

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)

MAIN_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html'
ELEMENT_TYPE = "//a[@href]"
RETRY_COUNT = 5
ZIP_URL_LIST = []

def main():
    
    # 1. Navigate to: https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html.
    driver = page_navigator(MAIN_URL)

    # 2. Capture href elements in a list after they render.
    href_elements = element_grabber(driver, ELEMENT_TYPE)

    # 3. Extract URLs for zip files from href elements.
    zip_url_list = url_extractor(href_elements)

def page_navigator(url:str) -> webdriver:

    driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.get(url)

    assert driver.current_url == 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/capitalbikeshare-data/index.html'
    
    logging.info(f'Successfully navigated to {driver.current_url}')

    return driver

def element_grabber(cbs_driver:webdriver, 
                    element_type:str) -> list:
    
    retries = RETRY_COUNT

    while retries > 0:

        try:
            WebDriverWait(cbs_driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, '.zip'))).get_attribute('href')
            elements = cbs_driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, element_type)
            time.sleep(2)

            assert len(elements) > 0
            logging.info(f'Successfully found {element_type} elements at {MAIN_URL}')

            break

        except:
            time.sleep(2)
            retries = retries - 1
            logging.warning(f'Failed to find href elements at {MAIN_URL}')
            logging.warning(f'Retries remaining: {retries}')

    return elements

def url_extractor(href_list:list) -> list:

    for element in href_list:
        ZIP_URL_LIST.append(element.get_attribute('href'))

    assert len(ZIP_URL_LIST) > 0
    zip_url_count = len(ZIP_URL_LIST)
    logging.info(f'Successfully found {zip_url_count} zip file URLs at {MAIN_URL}')

    return ZIP_URL_LIST

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Specifically, I want to write some unit tests, but I'm having trouble
> thinking of tests that don't replicate the assert statements already
> included in my code.

It seems your code is indeed embedding the tests in the possible tests as run time verifications.

You can either keep as this (since your code will fail at run time if something wrong happens) or re-write it starting from tests.

E.g.

test - Page landing

```
Given that we inject the URL "XYZ"
When the scrapper is started
Then the page landed is "XYZ"
```

[Then you write the production code that makes this test pass.
And continue with the rest of the behavior your wish to see in your program.](https://wiki.c2.com/?TestDrivenDevelopment)

[image]